# How do i provide the path to the --tab option for mysqldump on windows

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line

Using the command line on windows. Mysqldump does not accept the "" in the path name for the --tab= option.

I have tried the following:
`mysqldump -u root -p --tab=D:\DataDump myDB`
`mysqldump -u root -p --tab="D:\DataDump" myDB`
`mysqldump -u root -p --tab='D:\DataDump' myDB`
`mysqldump -u root -p --tab=D:\\DataDump myDB`

I get either a syntax error or ERROR Unknown command \D

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Short File Names
2. Use Proximity Paths: If your path contains spaces and you still want to use the --tab option, you can try using the old DOS-style proximity path notation. Instead of using double quotes, you can use the ~ character followed by the directory's short name.
3. Try renaming the folder.

Comment: This gives me a Syntax error

Answer (score 0):

> Using the command line on windows. Mysqldump does not accept the "" in
> the path name for the --tab= option

In fact it does accept.

Running the following command in windows.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqldump -u root -p --tab="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads" world
Enter password: *********

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>
```

Generates the following files in the Uploads directory ,

[image]

Some of the content of the country.txt

```
ABW Aruba   North America   Caribbean   193.00  \N  103000  78.4    828.00  793.00  Aruba   Nonmetropolitan Territory of The Netherlands    Beatrix 129 AW
AFG Afghanistan Asia    Southern and Central Asia   652090.00   1919    22720000    45.9    5976.00 \N  Afganistan/Afqanestan   Islamic Emirate Mohammad Omar   1   AF
AGO Angola  Africa  Central Africa  1246700.00  1975    12878000    38.3    6648.00 7984.00 Angola  Republic    José Eduardo dos Santos 56  AO
AIA Anguilla    North America   Caribbean   96.00   \N  8000    76.1    63.20   \N  Anguilla    Dependent Territory of the UK   Elisabeth II    62  AI
ALB Albania Europe  Southern Europe 28748.00    1912    3401200 71.6    3205.00 2500.00 Shqipëria   Republic    Rexhep Mejdani  34  AL
AND Andorra Europe  Southern Europe 468.00  1278    78000   83.5    1630.00 \N  Andorra Parliamentary Coprincipality        55  AD
ANT Netherlands Antilles    North America   Caribbean   800.00  \N  217000  74.7    1941.00 \N  Nederlandse Antillen    Nonmetropolitan Territory of The Netherlands    Beatrix 33  AN
ARE United Arab Emirates    Asia    Middle East 83600.00    1971    2441000 74.1    37966.00    36846.00    Al-Imarat al-´Arabiya al-Muttahida  Emirate Federation  Zayid bin Sultan al-Nahayan 65  AE
```

**Note**. I used the Uploads directory because of the `secure_file_priv`, mysql needs permitions to that directory.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                                          |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| secure_file_priv | C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\ |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See more on [mysqldump — A Database Backup Program](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tab)

Comment: mysql> mysqldump -u root -p --tab="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads" world;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u root -p --tab="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads" world' at line 1
mysql>

Comment: @JackofAllMasterofNone mysqldump needs to be executed in the server not inside MySQL as it can be seen clearly in my answer .

Comment: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqldump -u root -p --tab="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads" world;
Enter password: *************************
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'world;' when selecting the database

Comment: When using Workbench, I can see all databases (schemas).

Comment: @JackofAllMasterofNone wold is my schema in my test database, replace it with your schema name

Comment: It seems that I needed to have 2 command prompts open. One to connect to MySQL and the other to run the Mysqldump. I have completed this exercise successfully. Thanks for the help.